# how do i save my login details and redirect page properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

** i am trying to do save login details and it works but when `signin(true)` fuction called page get reload  infinity times **

```
signin(true)


// doing sign in

function onlogin(dataResult, is_check_login) {
    $("#preloader").show();
    var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
    if (dataResult.statusCode == 200) {
        $("#preloader").hide();
       
       var signedin_user_id = dataResult.row_id;

       // open dashboard if already logged in

        window.location.href = '../page/index.html';
        document.getElementById("dashboard_name").innerHTML = dataResult.name;



    } else if (dataResult.statusCode == 201) {
        $("#preloader").hide();

        if (is_check_login) {

            //open sign in form if not logged in
            window.location.href = '../page/signin.html';


        } else {
            $("#preloader").hide();

            console.log('invalid login');
        }
    }
}


function sign_in(is_check_login = false) {

    var signin_email = $('#signin_email').val();
    var signin_password = $('#signin_password').val();
    if (is_check_login || (signin_email != "" && signin_password != "")) {
        $.ajax({
            url: `https://www.name.com/page/php/${is_check_login ? "checklogin" : "login"}.php`,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                signin_email: signin_email,
                signin_password: signin_password
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                onlogin(result, is_check_login);
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert('Please fill all the field !');
    }


}
```

Comment: Your success callback calls `onlogin`, which calls `sign_in`, which calls `onlogin`.....

Comment: yes.. but what should i change in code? @ScottMarcus

Comment: It doesn't seem like after a successful login, you should call `onlogin`.

Comment: `signin(true)` means its already logged in so page should be redirect to dashboad @ScottMarcus